# How to test an init() function in jest that is called from constructor and then calls other async functions

Tags: unit-testing, async-await, jestjs, es6-class

I have the following code in javascript:

```js
class SampleClass {
  constructor(param1) {
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.init();
  }
  async init() {
    await this.getData();
    this.loadIframe();
  }
  async getData() {
    const response = fetch(url);
    const data = response.json();
    //set the response to class variable
    this.param2 = data;
  }
  loadIframe() {
    //some logic to load iframe.
  }
}
```

What would be the best approach to test this using jest?

Currently I am testing the constructor logic by mocking the init() function.

But **I also have to test the getData()** function. What should be the approach to test the getData() method.

I tried testing the getData() function **by not mocking the init() function and using async testing**, but I am **not sure** **where to use the await in the test** as the function is nested and called from within the init which is called from constructor.

```
it('should fetch data', async()=>{
   //some logic  
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to mock your methods of the `SampleClass`. My test environment is `node`, so I mock `fetch` method on `global` object. If your test environment is `browser`, the `fetch` method is on `window` object.

E.g.

`sampleClass.js`:

```js
class SampleClass {
  constructor(param1) {
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.init();
  }
  async init() {
    await this.getData();
    this.loadIframe();
  }
  async getData() {
    const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
    const response = fetch(url);
    const data = response.json();
    this.param2 = data;
  }
  loadIframe() {}
}

export { SampleClass };
```

`sampleClass.test.js`:

```js
import { SampleClass } from './sampleClass';

describe('60146073', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  describe('#constructor', () => {
    it('should consturt', () => {
      jest.spyOn(SampleClass.prototype, 'constructor');
      jest.spyOn(SampleClass.prototype, 'init').mockReturnValueOnce();
      const instance = new SampleClass('param1');
      expect(instance.param1).toBe('param1');
      expect(instance.init).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
  describe('#init', () => {
    it('should init', async () => {
      jest.spyOn(SampleClass.prototype, 'getData').mockResolvedValueOnce();
      jest.spyOn(SampleClass.prototype, 'loadIframe').mockReturnValueOnce();
      jest.spyOn(SampleClass.prototype, 'init').mockReturnValueOnce();
      const instance = new SampleClass();
      await instance.init();
      expect(instance.getData).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(instance.loadIframe).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });

  describe('#getData', () => {
    it('should fetch data', async () => {
      const mResponse = { json: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce({}) };
      global.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(mResponse);
      jest.spyOn(SampleClass.prototype, 'init').mockReturnValueOnce();
      const instance = new SampleClass();
      await instance.getData();
      expect(global.fetch).toBeCalledWith('https://stackoverflow.com/');
      expect(mResponse.json).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60146073/sampleClass.test.js
  60146073
    #constructor
      ✓ should consturt (3ms)
    #init
      ✓ should init (2ms)
    #getData
      ✓ should fetch data (2ms)

----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File            | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files       |     100 |      100 |      80 |     100 |                   
 sampleClass.js |     100 |      100 |      80 |     100 |                   
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.137s, estimated 5s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/60146073

Comment: What is the exact use of spying the constructor in  jest.spyOn(SampleClass.prototype, 'constructor'); I could omit that line and it would still work.

Comment: @user2053459 So that we can assert that the constructor of `SampleClass` is to be called. I miss one line: `expect(SampleClass.prototype.constructor).toBeCalled()`

Comment: @slideshowp2 I am getting type error when trying to spy on constructor,
`jest.spyOn(SampleClass.prototype, 'constructor');`
How to implement this test scenario with TypeScript & Jest